Livewire Search doesn't work correctly - always returns the same result
I'm facing an issue using Livewire and Laravel. I'm trying to implement search functionality for products on a page, but typing into the search bar always returns the same result, even if the search text changes.
Here is the code of my livewire class:
ProductList.php




<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Cigarette;
use App\Models\Liquid;
use Livewire\Component;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;

class ProductList extends Component
{
    public $search = '';

    public function render()
    {
        $searchTerm = trim($this->search);

        $filteredCigarettes = Cigarette::whereRaw('LOWER(name) like ?', ['%' . strtolower($searchTerm) . '%'])->get();
        $filteredLiquids = Liquid::whereRaw('LOWER(name) like ?', ['%' . strtolower($searchTerm) . '%'])->get();

        return view('livewire.product-list', [
            'cigarettes' => $filteredCigarettes,
            'liquids' => $filteredLiquids,
        ]);
    }
}






and here is the view of this livewire class:




<div class="grid">

    <input wire:model.live.debounce.1000ms="search" class="searchbar" type="text">

    {{-- Cigarettes --}}
    @forelse($cigarettes as $cigarette)
        <livewire:cigarette-card :cigarette="$cigarette"/>
    @empty
        <div class="#">
            No cigarettes in the database
        </div>
    @endforelse

    {{-- Liquids --}}
    @forelse($liquids as $liquid)
        <livewire:liquid-card :liquid="$liquid"/>
    @empty
        <div class="#">
            No liquids in the database
        </div>
    @endforelse
</div>





After some dump:




class ProductList extends Component
{
    public $search = '';

    public function render()
    {
        $searchTerm = trim($this->search);

        dump($this->search);

        dump(Cigarette::where('name', 'like', '%'.'Gene'.'%')->get());

        $filteredCigarettes = Cigarette::whereRaw('LOWER(name) like ?', ['%' . strtolower($searchTerm) . '%'])->get();
        $filteredLiquids = Liquid::whereRaw('LOWER(name) like ?', ['%' . strtolower($searchTerm) . '%'])->get();

        dump($filteredCigarettes);

        return view('livewire.product-list', [
            'cigarettes' => $filteredCigarettes,
            'liquids' => $filteredLiquids,
        ]);
    }
}





i got this:




"gene" // app\Livewire\ProductList.php:20 

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1345 ▼ // app\Livewire\ProductList.php:22
  #items: array:1 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#581 ▼ // app\Livewire\ProductList.php:27
  #items: array:1 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}





When I enter text into the search field, the query always returns only one result - "Pod Smok System". And it looks like:
https://i.ibb.co/f0ZH7PB/2024-12-11-094813.jpg
My database table with cigarettes looks like:
https://i.ibb.co/0tQ6cgg/2024-12-11-094127.jpg
I tried using whereRaw('LOWER(name) like ?', ...) to be case sensitive, but the problem persisted.
Also, I added debounce.500ms to the input field to reduce the frequency of requests to the server.
How can I properly configure Livewire search so that it updates correctly every time I type and returns the correct results instead of always returning the same results?
I would be grateful for your help!

Try making separate variables for cigarettes and liquids and update them when the search changes. Or you can write properties like this
public function getFilteredLiquidsProperty()
{
    $searchTerm = trim($this->search);
    return Liquid::where('name', 'like', "%{$searchTerm}%")->get();
}

and then pass them like this
return view('livewire.product-list', [
        'liquids' => $this->filteredLiquids,
    ]);

Or a lifecycle hook
public $cigarettes = [];
public $liquids = [];

public function updatedSearch($value)
{
    $searchTerm = trim($value);

    $this->cigarettes = Cigarette::where('name', 'like', "%{$searchTerm}%")->get();
    $this->liquids = Liquid::where('name', 'like', "%{$searchTerm}%")->get();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.product-list', [
        'cigarettes' => $this->cigarettes,
        'liquids' => $this->liquids,
    ]);
}


I've tried the 1st solution and I got the same problem, here are some screenshots:
code with liquids only: link
code with both products:link
output:link
The interesting thing is that in both cases I somehow get the last entry from the product tables: https://i.ibb.co/ZL4wf5F/2024-12-11-185338.jpg
PS: sorry if the pictures are awkward, I just want the problem to be visible and clear
(I'll try the second solution now)

I've tried 2 and it works, but:
1. before typing a name of the cigarette or liquid i have an empty page: https://i.ibb.co/6nB7RR5/2024-12-11-201456.jpg
2. finds the data correctly: https://i.ibb.co/522fv7G/2024-12-11-201632.jpg
3. after erasing the line, I see the entry that was found before clearing the line, and all the liquid entries: https://i.ibb.co/SBwRrqb/2024-12-11-201746.jpg
I tried adding mount() with variable initialization ($this->cigarettes = Cigarette::all(); and $this->liquids = Liquid::all();) but that returned an error with the same entry when searching
